# Lebesgue measure of $\{ u \ge \epsilon\}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $$u(x) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2(n+1)} 1_{(n,2n]}(x),$$
and show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, $\lambda(\{x \ | \ u(x) \ge \epsilon \}) \le 1/\epsilon$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the integral of $u$?

Comment: For fixed $x$, only the terms $a_n = 1/n^2(n + 1)$ with $n < x$ contribute to the sum. What kind of bound can you get for the sum of the $a_n$ over such $x$?

Comment: The integral is 1?

Comment: Correct. Now, how could that be related to $\lambda(\{u \geqslant \varepsilon\}) \leqslant 1/\varepsilon$?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $x$ is positive and large,
$$ u(x) = \sum_{\substack{n\geq\frac{x}{2}\\ n<x}}\frac{1}{n^2(n+1)}\approx \int_{x/2}^{x}\frac{dz}{z^2(z+1)}=\frac{1}{x}+\log(1+x)-\log(2+x)\approx\frac{3}{2x^2}. $$
Moreover, $u(x)$ is non-negative and Lebesgue integrable over $\mathbb{R}^+$. Since:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}u(x)\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)= 1 $$
your bound follows from Markov's inequality. We may also compute:

$$ \|u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^+)}^2=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^3(n+1)^2}+2\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\sum_{\substack{m<n\\ m\geq\frac{n}{2}}}\frac{2m-n}{n^2 m^2(n+1)(m+1)}$$
and get a slightly better bound from Chebyshev's inequality.